# How to configure single instance Beanstalk Node.js app without ELB?

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am migrating an app to Beanstalk, and I want to make it clear that the following questions are only about **single instance** configuration **without** using **Elastic Load Balancer**.

Current configuration:

- Node.js app running on ports 8081 (HTTP) and 8082 (HTTPS)
- Node.js serving static files under /server/public at /
- Node.js serving APIs at /api

My basic question is, how do I get incoming traffic to 80 being redirected to 8081? What settings and where do I have to do? Do I need to set up a proxy, such as Nginx, and if I do, what kind of settings do I have to do? I tried going through AWS documentation, but it contains mostly information on setting up Elastic Load Balancer (ELB), and in this case I especially want to set up the system without ELB.

The next question is, what settings and where do I have to do if I wanted to terminate HTTPS on Nginx proxy? I tried the [official instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html), but couldn't get them working.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can setup nginx as a proxy to pass all requests on port 80 (or 443) to the respective nginx port.  Like, :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:8081;
    }
```

Comment: Where do I put that configuration?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. It seems there was some configurational conflict in my environment which got fixed by recreating it.